# In pair programming, what is each role named, and why?

Tags: pair-programming, etymology

I've heard the person at the keyboard named the "driver", and the other person named the "navigator".  I've imagined rally car racers, where the person at the wheel just *cannot* keep up with *everything* that's happening, and they *must* have the help of the "navigator", who's shouting volumes and volumes of directions at them to, literally, keep them "out of the weeds", much like a person at the keyboard is kept "on course" by the person in the second chair.

What are the more/most commonly accepted terms for the two roles in pair programming, and (if it's not obvious) are they borrowed from any earlier professions?

Comment: I don't know why, but that rally metaphor just make me imagine slamming head-first into a tree. But yeah, you've basically listed the role names and answered your own question.

Comment: Alternatively you can call navigator a 'shotgun'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The driver (or less commonly pilot) has hands on with the keyboard and is right there, banging out the code.

The navigator (or observer, or less commonly co-driver or co-pilot) is sitting alongside with the reference documents making sure the code is going the right way.

The navigator has a better perspective of what's coming up, and isn't just worrying about the mechanics of typing away.

Comment: "worrying about the mechanics of typing away.", haha, really, isn't typing like breathing to most of us by now?

Answer (score 0):

The way I think of it is nothing more than the driver holds the steering wheel (keyboard), the other guy needs a title and the rally metaphor works for most geeks.

I never thought of of extending the metaphor to the tree as suggested by @Bart

Answer (score 0):

> What are the more/most commonly accepted terms for the two roles in pair programming?

Driver and navigator/observer.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the improperly paired combination of driver/back seat. It's annoying that one is a role name and the other a location.